# In Zope/ZODB, how to delete objects from a BTreeFolder2

Tags: python, zope, zodb

I'm a Zope newb. I need to delete a bunch of objects from a BTreeFolder2 from say, id 1 to id 15000. When going to the admin web interface, the objects are not ordered correctly so I can't just select and delete them. The order is strictly alpha so I get:

1
10
1000
10000
10001
etc...

My guess is I will have to use zopectl -debug and issue some Python commands to select and delete those objects.

I have no idea how to do that. Can you help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.restrictedTraverse('/path/to/folder').manage_delObjects(list_of_ids)
transaction.commit()
```

Comment: Is list_of_ids supposed to be replaced by the actual list of all 15000 ids? I need to delete everything from 1 to 15000, is there no way I can give it a range instead?

Comment: you have to pass in a list of individual as IDs

Comment: ID as are *always* *strings* in Zope and *never* integers. Instead of asking ten times back, try it out.

Comment: @md1337, you don't of course have to type all the ids by hand. If they are simply numbers from 1 to 15000: `app.restrictedTraverse('/path/to/folder').manage_delObjects([str(i) for i in range(1,15001)])` ought to do it.

Comment: @Duncan- thanks, that will work. At least you're not being an ass about it unlike Adolph Jung.